# Google Charts export as image

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I'd like to get simple pie google chart (like this one https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart) and set to PDF as image.

To create PDF I use laravel-dompdf, which is a laravel wrapper for DOMPDF library. This library doesn't support javascript.

It should be in background. I mean that I don't have step where I display html in browser to save charts as image from javascript.

Any hints? It's also possible to use different similar library but I could not found nothing interesting.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is what you looking for a headless browser perhaps? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser

Comment: why not use a php chart-library?

Comment: @wayneOS I have impression that php charts also generate javascript code to draw on canvas not static images.

Comment: @jaroApp this library https://phpchart.com/examples/ can generate image-files from the charts. totally on server-side without any javascript.

Comment: Google charts are used as data collection devices. Similar to Google analytics. It does not only collect your pie data, and your website data, but also the data of anyone loading the pie chart. That's why it is only available as javascript. It has to run client side to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Google offers a function called getImageURI() for its charts. 
This will return the chart as an image but in base64 encoded format. It's described under https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing. Using this and a headless broswer such as PhantomJS you can get that base64 encoded image.

You can use https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs to load the webpage with the chart on it and then fetch the base64 encoded image from that website.

I would implement a javascript function that posts the base64 string to an endpoint and then you will be able to save that as a pdf/png/jpg or in any other formats.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Could you explain last paragraph in more detail?